# Export GridView to TXT, then upload file to server

Tags: c#, arrays, file, gridview, upload

Basically what I want to do is export an array (or GridView) to a file called "getpathin.dat". That is easy, but the method I am using downloads the file to my computer, which is what I don't want.

I want to write an array to either a PRE-EXISTING file that is on the server OR create a new file on the server in a folder, and this new file will contain either the array or the gridview, which I have stored in the array.

i'll be doing this in...

Visual Studio 2008/SQL Server using C#

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have your exact solution in mind but I wanted to mention that if you still have your datasource at the time you want to serialize it to disk and it's a datatable, the datatablehas a nice .WriteXml() method.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I need a simple tab delimited file because I am basically taking the GridView, storing it into an array, then writing that array into a giant string with tabs between the columns and new lines for each row. This file will be read by an executable created by MATLAB.